# SwiftUI AppStorage is not synchronized with 1 View & 2 ViewModels

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created AppStorage variable ("test") observed by 1 View(named TestView) & 2 ViewModels(named SetViewModel, ResetViewModel each)

When I set the value of "test" in SetViewModel, onChange is called in TestView and newValue was correct.

But, the value of "test" is not updated in ResetViewModel except the first time.

I'll attach the sample code.

**TestView**

```
struct TestView: View {
    @AppStorage("test") var test: String = ""
    
    let resetViewModel = ResetViewModel()
    let setViewModel = SetViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                print("Button1 set test data")
                setViewModel.setTestData()
            } label: {
                Text("Button1")
                    .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
            }
            
            Button {
                print("Button2 reset test data")
                resetViewModel.resetTestData()
            } label: {
                Text("Button2")
                    .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: test) { newValue in
            print("onChange newValue: \(newValue)")
            resetViewModel.printTestData()
        }
    }
}
```

**SetViewModel**

```
class SetViewModel {
    @AppStorage("test") var test: String = ""
    
    func setTestData() {
        test = "aaa"
    }
}
```

**ResetViewModel**

```
class ResetViewModel {
    @AppStorage("test") var test: String = ""
    
    func printTestData() {
        print("test: \(test)")
    }
    
    func resetTestData() {
        test = ""
    }
}
```

And the result is like this

```
Button1 set test data
onChange newValue: aaa
test: aaa
Button2 reset test data
onChange newValue: 
test: 
Button1 set test data
onChange newValue: aaa
test:
```

As printed, the AppStorage value is different from the newValue of onChange. How is it possible?

Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: This might help: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/appstorage-explained/

Comment: Your view models are classes that are `let` and not being observed. SwiftUI has no way of knowing when a change has happened so it can reload the `body`

Comment: we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, you have to learn the view struct and property wrappers

Comment: @loremipsum For this case to test AppStorage, I think I don't need to reload body because I do not have any UI components to show property of view model.
Also, the problem is that, "test" of SetViewModel is not changed after being called onChange in TestView(this means that AppStorage value is changed but not synchronized only in SetViewModel).

Comment: @malhal Do you mean that I should not use MVVM pattern for SwiftUI? or I need to add property wrappers like ObservableObject, ObservedObject? I removed property wrappers from my sample code on purpose, thinking that AppStorage would works alone, regradless of other property wrappers

Comment: @RobC Wow..this article is perfect. The downsides described in the article of AppStorage is what I experienced. Thank you!!

Comment: I have not read the article but if my suspicion is true the DynamicProperty inheritance keeps you from getting an updated value if you are not observing. You have to use it in conjunction with a View or an ObsevableObject and it’s respective wrappers. Read about SwiftUIs DynamicProperty in the documentation.

Comment: I've run into a lack of @AppStorage update, *when reading* even when used in an ObservableObject. My hypothesis is if @AppStorage is used outside of a `View`, the value doesn't get updated properly. I think some fancy caching is going on. I'd prefer if reads just read from UserDefaults every time.

Answer (score -1):

I have also already experienced some problems with `AppStorage` related to view updates. If you don't find a better solution, I would suggest a workaround.
You could make `test` in `ResetViewModel` computed like this:

```
var test: String {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "test") ?? ""
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "test")
    }
}
```

This way, the value of `test` gets explicitly loaded from or written to the user defaults file each time the variable is accessed.